# ListBox Not displaying values when sorted alphabetically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

This is my sorting logic alphabetic wise

```
  string selectedVal = lstSelectionTags.SelectedValue;
        SortedList sortedItems = new SortedList();
        for (int i = 0; i < lstSelectionTags.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            sortedItems.Add(lstSelectionTags.Items[i].Text, lstSelectionTags.Items[i].Value);
        }
        lstSelectionTags.Items.Clear();
        lstSelectionTags.DataSource = sortedItems;
        lstSelectionTags.DataTextField = "key";
        lstSelectionTags.DataValueField = "value";
        lstSelectionTags.DataBind();
```

when i display items first time in my Listbox by using the below give code

```
   string valueField = Convert.ToString(lstSelectionSub.SelectedItem);
            int catID = Convert.ToInt32(lstSelectionSub.SelectedValue);
            util = new Utilities();
            dt1 = util.GetSubTags_PD(catID, false);
            string[] lines = new string[100];
            List<string> lines1 = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string s1 = dt1.Rows[i][0].ToString();

                if (s1 != "")
                {
                    lines = Regex.Split(s1, ",");

                    if (!lines1.Contains(lines.ToString()))
                    {
                        lines1.AddRange(lines);
                    }
                }
            }

            lstSelectionTags.DataSource = lines1.Distinct();

            lstSelectionTags.DataBind();
```

It works fine initially and displays the Data but when i do sorting and then try and access the values i don't get any value in the `ListBox`

**EDIT:** There seems to be some issue with sorting after sorting the Listbox has a key and value as the DataValue and DataText Field whereas when i rebind it there is no DataValue and DataText Field. Please help.

**ISSUE  SOLVED :** Just used

```
                if (lines1.Count > 0)
                {
                    lstSelectionTags.DataSource = null;
                    lstSelectionTags.Items.Clear();

                    lstSelectionTags.DataSource = lines1.Distinct();

                    lstSelectionTags.DataTextField = null;
                    lstSelectionTags.DataValueField = null;
                    lstSelectionTags.DataBind();
                }
```

Comment: Since you're using a `DataTable` anyway (and i assume that the data comes from the DB), i would recommend to `ORDER BY` in the database instead.

Comment: But i have a button on which i have to apply my sorting logic

Comment: Always do what you can in the database, that's more efficient and reusable.

Comment: The Client wants it this way that's why

Comment: If you sorting server side in memory it will, it would, I imagine, be quicker to do another round trip to the DB and use ORDER BY

Comment: Plus i cannot use Order By as the Items come in the same row that i am adding to the ListBox

Comment: One thing have noticed i get the items in the DataSource but they don't get displayed

Comment: Hm your code actually works fine on my machine.(I mocked the initialization part of course).

Comment: If you mean that you don't have a *different* 'key' and 'value', you would be right. Since you're initializing with a list, the `Text` and `Value` properties would be the same.  Or are you saying that the list shows up empty?

Comment: The List contains values i mean 'lines1' contains items but they don't get displayed once i sort the list alphabetically and try accessing the values in the ListBox